# Angular in ASP MVC project: template not displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I´m new to angular and followed a youtube-tutorial on how to use it in an asp mvc project. That worked fine, I got the following structure:

[image]

I then worked on my app.component.ts, which looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'chtest',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`,
})
export class AppComponent
{
    constructor() { }

    name = 'Angular';
}
```

I also tried the above code with templateUrl (and app.component.html), but that didn´t work too.

My app.module.ts looks like this:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports:        [ BrowserModule ],
    declarations:   [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap:      [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule
{
    constructor() { }
}
```

I then created a simple view just holding the following:

```
<chtest></chtest>
```

When I run the application there is nothing displayed. I expected it to show "Hello Angular", but I think I´m missing something here?

Folders like node_modules are there, as I said, the youtube-tutorial worked (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbHSTJBhJ44)

I´m running Visual Studio Professional 2017, v15.8.4

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

I tried something else from w3schools:

```
My first expression: {{ 5 + 5 }}
```

This is displaying nothing but

[image]

Comment: I advise you to use asp.net core 2.1 so find the angular project ready

Comment: if you want I can show you how

Comment: Hey, can't use core because I have to use angular with an existing mvc project. This is just a study for myself to learn angular.